# How do I sort through equal tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the information from the html that has text in it.
When I am using the

```
find('dl', class_="definition-list")
```

or

```
findNext('dl', class_="definition-list")
```

it returns nothing.

An example of a website is (it is looped, to move through several): https://www.finn.no/realestate/homes/ad.html?finnkode=216521178

I am trying to get only this part only;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price data is in the third `div` of class `panel`. You can easily get that with `.find_all()`.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
}

product_url = "https://www.finn.no/realestate/homes/ad.html?finnkode=216521178"
page_content = requests.get(product_url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'lxml').find_all("div", class_="panel")[2]
print("\n".join(soup.getText(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")))
```

Output:

```
Prisantydning
3 790 000 kr
Fellesgjeld
72 827 kr
Omkostninger
108 120 kr
Totalpris
3 970 947 kr
Felleskost/mnd.
3 128 kr
```

> This works with any URL on that page. :-]

Comment: So I was missing the [2]!! Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for such a long time now!!